# Why can't I access my class variables in my main program?

Tags: c#

Like I said in the title, I cannot access my variables from my class. Initially, the error was "CS0122: 'Game.win' is inaccessible due to its protection level." After looking at other people who had similar errors, I made a few changes to my code, which fixed the CS0122 error, but this introduced a new error, "CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Game.win'."

I've looked up this error as well, but I can't seem to make any sense of the solutions that people posted. This is my main program code below.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game game1 = new Game();
            game1.SetQuestion1(GetInput());
            game1.game();
            game1.DisplayAll();
        }
        public static string GetInput()
        {
            do
            {
                string input;
                WriteLine("Please enter your choice: Rock - 1, Paper - 2, Scissors - 3");
                input = ReadLine();
                return input;
            }
            while (Game.win < 4 || Game.lose < 4 || Game.usermoney == 0);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my classes code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    public class Game
    {

            public double usermoney = 100;
            public double win = 0;
            public double lose = 0;
            public double userchoice, computerchoice;

        public void game()
        {
            if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 0)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                lose++;
                usermoney = usermoney - 10;
            }
        }
        public double SetQuestion1(string param1)
        {
            userchoice = double.Parse(param1);
            return userchoice;
        }
        public double Computer()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            computerchoice = rnd.Next(1, 3);
            return computerchoice;
        }
        public void DisplayAll()
        {
            WriteLine("User chose: " + userchoice + ", Computer chose: " + computerchoice + ". Remember, 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors");
            WriteLine("User balance is " + usermoney);
            if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
            {
                WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
            {
                WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
            {
                WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine("User Loses - -$10");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The solutions I read mentioned removing "static" from a method or object, but my variables aren't in a method so I am unsure of what I am supposed to do, and I would really appreciate some advice on how to proceed from here.

Comment: You are trying to Access 'win' variable which is a member of Game class, You need to make an object of Game Class than you can access it through that object, otherwise you need to make 'win' variable static , because only static variables can be accessed like this. i.e( ClassName.variableName)

Comment: Your variables are not in method but in class, YOu need to make them static to access them directly by their ClassName :)

Comment: The `game1` should be a static field and you could read from the in your `while` loop

Comment: C# is an object oriented language, the members you are trying to access `Game.win` are fields of the `Game` object. As they are not static, you must first initialize an instance of your `Game` class.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm in an intro programming class, but do you mean that I should put the variables into a new static method? I tried to create a new static method to act as a container for these variables, but this made the variables inaccessible to the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class Program
{
    public static Game game1 {get; set;}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        game1 = new Game();
        game1.SetQuestion1(GetInput());
        game1.game();
        game1.DisplayAll();
    }

    public static string GetInput()
    {
        string input = "";

        do
        {
            WriteLine("Please enter your choice: Rock - 1, Paper - 2, Scissors - 3");
            input = ReadLine();
        }
        while (game1.win < 4 || game1.lose < 4 || game1.usermoney == 0);

        return input;
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that I can run the program, I see a new problem, the loop isn't causing the program to repeat. It only runs 1 time, even though wins and losses are less than 4.

Comment: because you return input already. getting out from loop. under while clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually a couple of problems here. The first is that the instance of your `Game`-class exists only within `Main`. So referring to it from any other method or even class is impossible. That applies to your `GetInput`-method as well. In order to use that instance, you may pass it as parameter to `GetInput`:

```
 public static string GetInput(Game game)
 {
     do
     {
         string input;
         WriteLine("Please enter your choice: Rock - 1, Paper - 2, Scissors - 3");
         input = ReadLine();
         return input;
     }
     while (game.win < 4 || game.lose < 4 || game.usermoney == 0);
 }
```

Now all  you have to do is to provide the `Game`-instance from `Main` to that method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Game game1 = new Game();
    game1.SetQuestion1(GetInput(game1));
    game1.game();
    game1.DisplayAll();
}
```

No need for anything `static` here (expect `Main` and `GetInput` of course).

Just an asside: it´s uaually a bad idea to exit from any arbitrary locations in your code - so is `Environment.Exit`. You may instead return a `bool` from your `game`-method that indicates if the program should exit:

```
public void game()
{
    ...
    else if (userchoice == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Game game1 = new Game();
    game1.SetQuestion1(GetInput());
    if(!game1.game())
        return; // here you get the return-value of game and exit program if user typed zero.
    game1.DisplayAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your class variables, because they declared inside of method, not as fields or properties. In this app I would recommend to pass game1 to your GetInput method as a reference it will give you access to your object.

```
namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game game1 = new Game();
            game1.SetQuestion1(GetInput(game1));
            game1.game();
            game1.DisplayAll();

            Console.WriteLine("End of game");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetInput(Game game)
        {
            do
            {
                string input;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your choice: Rock - 1, Paper - 2, Scissors - 3");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                return input;
            }
            while (game.win < 4 || game.lose < 4 || game.usermoney == 0);
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Game
    {
        public double usermoney = 100;
        public double win = 0;
        public double lose = 0;
        public double userchoice, computerchoice;

        public void game()
        {
            if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
            {
                win++;
                usermoney = usermoney + 20;
            }
            else if (userchoice == 0)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                lose++;
                usermoney = usermoney - 10;
            }
        }
        public double SetQuestion1(string param1)
        {
            userchoice = double.Parse(param1);
            return userchoice;
        }
        public double Computer()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            computerchoice = rnd.Next(1, 3);
            return computerchoice;
        }
        public void DisplayAll()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User chose: " + userchoice + ", Computer chose: " + computerchoice + ". Remember, 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors");
            Console.WriteLine("User balance is " + usermoney);
            if (userchoice == 1 && computerchoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else if (userchoice == 2 && computerchoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else if (userchoice == 3 && computerchoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Wins - +$20");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User Loses - -$10");
            }
        }
    }
}
```